# Taking object without empty properties in Linq

Tags: linq

I want to take `pa` but empty `MG` props.

```
Parent pa = new Parent()
               {
                   MC = new Child[]
                            {
                                new Child() {M1 = 1},
                                new Child() {M1 = 2},
                                new Child() {M1 = 3},
                            },
                   MG = new GrandChild[]
                            {
                                new GrandChild() {M2 = "1"},
                                new GrandChild() {M2 = ""},
                                new GrandChild() {M2 = ""},
                                new GrandChild() {M2 = "4"},
                            },
                   MP = "just string prop",
               };
```

I know this is not true but wanna take my object like this way:

```
var vv = pa.MG.Where(_p=>_p.M2!="").Select(_k=>_k.**parent**)
```

Comment: what is "_k.**parent**  ?  Maybe if you described what you are trying to do, it would be easier to tell you how to do it.

Comment: I want to take pa object without empty elements of MG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pa.MG = pa.MG.Where(gc => gc.M2 != "").ToArray();
```

Comment: yes... IT isss... Why i didn't think to change property's value :(